# Public Shared Variable Shared Between Users?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've taken over the maintenance of the website (ASP.NET VB) and on one particular page I noticed the below code

```
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Public Shared UserNumber As String

Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Init

    UserNumber = Session("UserNumber")

    ...

End Sub
```

My question is whether the variable UserNumber can be accessed or changed by any other user than the current one?

Many thanks

Comment: Yes; as a `Shared` variable, it is accessible to all instances... therefore, all users of the app that run on the same process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `Shared` variable is the same as a `static` variable in C#.

These can be shared across all instances, therefore different users would share the same variable.

Looking at the variable name, I would assume you would need to remove this `Shared`

---

You are applying a `Session` variable value to the `Shared String` on `Page_Init`.

Therefore each time the user loads the page, their session variable will override the current value.

---

If you are not using this variable outside of this class, then I would recommend changing it to:

```
Protected UserNumber As String
```

Comment: So if the code is simply changed to

    Public UserNumber As String

the variable would only be accessible to the current user?

Comment: @BugLover However are you using this variable outside of this class? If not, change it to `Protected`

Comment: Many thanks Curt, I'll change it to Protected UserNumber As String as it's only being used on this page

Comment: Worth noting when talking about static and instances in ASP.NET is that basically every request is handled by a different Thread. But actually things are more complicated: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38501/Multi-Threading-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT** My initial answer was incorrect. Trying again...

Technically, as @Curt indicated, a `Shared` variable is shared across instances of the class.

However, with the code as is, it is less likely that the value will be shared amongst users as it is set to each user's local copy of the value in their Session in `Page_Init`.

There is a possible "race condition" where after the shared variable `UserNumber` has been initialised in `Page_Init`, and another user submits a request which updates the value of that variable from their session, the first user will then see the second user's value. i.e. users can see other user's values for concurrent requests.

Instead, I recommend using a `ReadOnly` non-shared property to get the value from the Session once:

```
 Private mUserNumber As String
 Public ReadOnly Property UserNumber As String
      Get
           If String.IsNullOrEmpty(mUserNumber) Then
               mUserNumber = Session("UserNumber")
           End If
           Return mUserNumber
      End Get
 End Property
```

This uses a pattern called "Lazy-loading", which I use in read-only properties a lot on pages to improve performance and readability of code.

Comment: Thanks for the replies but I see conflicting answers

I realise Session is kept separate between users but my question is whether user B would be able to effect the value of the variable UserNumber for user A?

Comment: The `Session` dictionary is, but what about the `Shared String`? Wouldn't the different session variables be updating the same shared variable?

Comment: -1. You are right about the `Session` dictionary, but the *variable UserNumber* (this is what the question is about, not `Session("UserNumber")`) *is* shared between all users.

Comment: Sorry GrefL, I'm just seeing your edited response now. Many thanks the above code looks very useful.