# Code works when single user viewing but page goes crazy when multiple users are viewing same page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Below are the aspx and vb code file for the problem page. The problem page works when only one user is logged in and viewing. Although, when another user logs in and views the same page then this happens ard(i) <> xxz(i)

```
Then Response.Redirect("../vwall/vwall_tour.aspx?tour_id=" & ddlAvailableTours.SelectedValue)
                End If
```

And the page reloads repetitively. So, ard(i) <> xxz(i) happens when multiple users are logged in viewing. How can one user be affected by another user viewing and making selections on the same page? Everything is fine with one user not when multiple users are playing around on this page.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="vwall_tour.aspx.vb" Inherits="vwall_tour2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

<script src="../js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.4.min.js" type="text/javascript">         </script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.4.min.js">            </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function OpenTourManager() {
    document.location.href = 'manage_tours.aspx';
    //document.location.href = 'manage_tours.aspx?tourid=' +   
      document.getElementById('ddlAvailableTours').options[document.getElementById('dd    lAvailableTours').selectedIndex].value;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1"   style="height:100%; vertical-align:middle" runat="server">
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=100% background="../images/gray.jpg">
<tr>
<td><img src="../images/cyberco-banner.gif" height="35px" alt="CYBERCO" /></td>
<td><asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSignOut" Text = "Sign Out" /></td>               
<td><input type = "button" value ="Change Password" onclick="javascript: document.location.href = '../changepassword.aspx';" id="btnChangePass"/></td>
<td></td>
<td><asp:Label ID ="lblUsername" runat="server"> </asp:Label></td>
<td width="400px">&nbsp;</td>
<td><asp:DropDownList ID = "ddlAvailableTours" runat="server" Width="250px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectionChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList></td>
<td><asp:Button runat="server"   id="btnSetDefaultTour"  Text="Set as default" /></td>
<td><input type='button' value='Manage Video Wall' onclick="javascript: OpenTourManager(); "/></td>
<td><input type="hidden"  id ="startstop" onclick= "javascript: vwallStartStop();"  /></td><td>(Fullscreen->&nbsp;F11)<!--<input type="button" value="Fullscreen mode" onclick="    toggleFull()" />--></td>
 </tr>
   </table>
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"  /><asp:Timer ID="Timer1" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" runat="server" Interval="5000" /><table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 id="main" style="height:100%; width:100%; padding:0px; margin:0px; background-color:#000000;">
<tr><td align=right style="vertical-align:top; border:0px; padding:0px;" align=top padding=0 valign=top class='header_row' id="tdheader">
    <div id="header" class="style1">


            <div id = "clockid"  style="visibility:hidden;  border:0px; padding:0px;" > clock</div>&nbsp;
       <!---<table border=2 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 padding=0 style="text-align:center;height:564;width:100%;padding:0;margin:0;" bgcolor=#425081 >-->
                    <tr>
                        <td padding=0  width=0px" width=0%>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up_setdefault" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline">    

                                <Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" /></Triggers>
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label id="StockPrice" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    <fieldset style="border:0; margin=0px; cellpadding=0; padding=0px; cellspacing=0; align=right; width=0px;" width=0%>    
                                    </fieldset> 
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <!--</table>-->
                <tr><td padding=0 style="border:0px; padding:0px;">    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litTableInner1"></asp:Literal></td></tr></table>
<!-- cut script -->

<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litCreatePlayersScript"></asp:Literal>
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litCreateUpdateScript"></asp:Literal>                        
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then the vb code file...

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Net

Public Class vwall_tour2
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Public Shared xxz(9) As String
'Protected default_wstr As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("default_wstr")
'Dim xxz = {"Off", "Off", "Off", "Off", "Off", "Off", "Off", "Off", "Off"}

Protected Sub vwall_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim thisUser As New cyberUser(User.Identity.Name, (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("timsConnectionString").ToString()))
    Me.lblUsername.Text = User.Identity.Name

    Dim auto_refresh_users As String()
    auto_refresh_users = Split(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("wall_logins_noexpire").ToString, ",")
    Dim lausername As String
    For Each lausername In auto_refresh_users
        If Trim(lausername) = User.Identity.Name Then
            Dim s As New StringBuilder
            s.AppendLine("setTimeout ( 'reloadit();', reloadtime ); ")
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "loadAfterSigninFromVwall", s.ToString(), True)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    ' if not found, will time out after 2 hrs and have to log in again 

    Dim selected_tour_id As Integer
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        'btnAdmin.Visible = False

        Dim ds As DataSet
        ds = dataFetcher.fillDataset("User_SelectTours " & thisUser.userid, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("timsConnectionString").ConnectionString, False)
        ddlAvailableTours.DataSource = ds
        ddlAvailableTours.DataValueField = "tour_id"
        ddlAvailableTours.DataTextField = "tour_name"
        ddlAvailableTours.DataBind()

        If Not Request.QueryString("tour_id") Is Nothing Then
            Try
                selected_tour_id = Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString("tour_id"))
            Catch ex As Exception
                selected_tour_id = ddlAvailableTours.Items(0).Value
            End Try
        ElseIf thisUser.default_tour_id <> -1 Then
            selected_tour_id = thisUser.default_tour_id
        Else
            selected_tour_id = ddlAvailableTours.Items(0).Value
        End If

        Dim itemfound As Boolean = False
        Dim item As ListItem
        For Each item In ddlAvailableTours.Items
            If item.Value = selected_tour_id Then

                item.Selected = True
                itemfound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If Not itemfound Then 'default or querystring tour_id not found 
            ddlAvailableTours.SelectedIndex = -1
            ddlAvailableTours.Items(0).Selected = True
        End If
        Me.ddlAvailableTours_SelectedIndexChanged(Nothing, Nothing)
    End If ' notpostback 

End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    StockPrice.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
    'TimeOfPrice.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
End Sub

Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
        Dim thisUser As New cyberUser(User.Identity.Name, (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("timsConnectionString").ToString()))
        ''load the page 

        Dim selected_tour_id As Integer
        selected_tour_id = ddlAvailableTours.SelectedValue

        Dim t As user_Tour
        For Each t In thisUser.user_Tours
            If t.tour_id = selected_tour_id Then
                StockPrice.Text = GetOverrideStatus(t)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        ''''''
    End If
End Sub

Function GetOverrideStatus(ByVal tour As user_Tour) As String
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim rstrf As New StringBuilder
    'create the playlist string 

    Dim playlists As String()
    Dim phaseitems As String()
    Dim numPlayers As Integer = tour.num_cols * tour.num_rows
    ReDim playlists(numPlayers - 1)
    Dim dsd As DataSet
    Dim stream_address As String
    Dim VideoLabel As Object
    Dim ard(9) As String

    'ard = {"Off", "Off", "Off", "Off"}
    Array.Clear(ard, 0, ard.Length)
    For Each p In tour.phases
        phaseitems = p.str_all_items.Split(",")

        For i = 0 To numPlayers - 1

            Dim s_id As String = phaseitems(i)
            If p.tour_phase_id > 1 Then
                playlists(i) &= ", "
            End If
            If Not s_id = "empty" And Not s_id = "" Then
                dsd = dataFetcher.fillDataset("ListImageAllFields '" & s_id & "'", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("timsConnectionString").ConnectionString, False)

                ard(i) = dsd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("active_override")
                ' rstrf.AppendLine("A" + ard(i))
                ' rstr.AppendLine(ard(i))
                If ard(i) <> xxz(i) Then
                    'Response.Write("<script>window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href </script>")
                    Response.Redirect("/media_dev/vwall/vwall_tour.aspx?tour_id=" & ddlAvailableTours.SelectedValue)
                End If

                ' If ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("active_override") = "On" Then
                'Response.Redirect("../default.aspx")
                ' End If


                'playlists(i) &= "'" & stream_address & "'"
            Else ' empty spot 
                'playlists(i) &= "'../images/tours/tour_empty_space.png'"

            End If 's not blank 
        Next
    Next
    'If ard(0) <> xxz(0) Or ard(1) <> xxz(1) Or ard(2) <> xxz(2) Or ard(3) <> xxz(3) Then
    'Response.Write("<script>window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href </script>")
    'Response.Redirect("../vwall/vwall_tour.aspx?tour_id=" & ddlAvailableTours.SelectedValue)
    ' End If

    'Return ard.ToString("C")
    Return ard(0).ToString() + ard(1).ToString() + ard(2).ToString() + ard(3).ToString() + ard(4).ToString() + ard(5).ToString() + ard(6).ToString() + ard(7).ToString() + ard(8).ToString()
End Function

Sub writeTableString(ByVal tour As user_Tour)
    Dim returnstr As New StringBuilder
    Dim td_width, td_height As Integer

    td_width = Math.Floor(100 / tour.num_cols)
    td_height = Math.Floor(100 / tour.num_rows) 'was 90

    Dim rstr As New StringBuilder
    Dim countinner, countouter As Integer
    countinner = 0
    countouter = 0
    Do
        rstr.AppendLine("<tr>")
        Do
            rstr.AppendLine("<td style='width:" & td_width & "%; height:" & td_height & "%;'><a runat='server' id='player" & (countinner + (countouter * tour.num_cols)) & "' href='#'></a></td>")
            countinner += 1
        Loop Until countinner = tour.num_cols
        rstr.AppendLine("</tr>")
        countouter += 1
        countinner = 0
    Loop Until countouter = tour.num_rows
    rstr.AppendLine("<script> document.getElementById('tdheader').colSpan='" & tour.num_cols & "';</script>")

    Me.litTableInner1.Text = rstr.ToString
End Sub

Sub writeScriptForPlayers(ByVal tour As user_Tour)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim rstr As New StringBuilder
    'create the playlist string 
    Dim playlists As String()
    Dim phaseitems As String()
    Dim numPlayers As Integer = tour.num_cols * tour.num_rows
    ReDim playlists(numPlayers - 1)
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim stream_address As String
    Dim VideoLabel As Object
    Array.Clear(xxz, 0, xxz.Length)
    For Each p In tour.phases
        phaseitems = p.str_all_items.Split(",")

        For i = 0 To numPlayers - 1

            Dim s_id As String = phaseitems(i)
            If p.tour_phase_id > 1 Then
                playlists(i) &= ", "
            End If
            If Not s_id = "empty" And Not s_id = "" Then
                ds = dataFetcher.fillDataset("ListImageAllFields '" & s_id & "'", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("timsConnectionString").ConnectionString, False)

                xxz(i) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("active_override")
                rstr.AppendLine("B" + xxz(i))
                If ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("active_override") = "Off" Then
                    If ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("hq_viewcapable") = "Y" Then
                        If ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("hq_firstresponder") = "Y" Then
                            stream_address = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("AddressRTMP_hq").ToString()
                        Else
                            stream_address = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("AddressRTMP").ToString()
                        End If
                    Else
                        stream_address = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("AddressRTMP").ToString()
                    End If
                Else : stream_address = "../overridden.swf"
                End If
                playlists(i) &= "'" & stream_address & "'"
                '  Else ' empty spot 
                'playlists(i) &= "'../images/tours/tour_empty_space.png'"

            End If 's not blank 

        Next
    Next

    ' end creating playlist strings 

    Dim countinner, countouter As Integer
    countinner = 0
    countouter = 0
    rstr.AppendLine("<script type='text/javascript'>")
    Do
        Do
            countinner += 1
        Loop Until countinner = tour.num_cols
        countouter += 1
        countinner = 0
    Loop Until countouter = tour.num_rows
    ''write the players 
    countinner = 0
    countouter = 0
    Do
        Do
            rstr.AppendLine("flowplayer('player" & (countinner + (countouter * tour.num_cols)) & "', '../flowplayer/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.5.swf', {  key: '#$34tg5y5y5hytr', logo: { url:'../images/CYBERLOGO.PNG', opacity: 0.65, top: 10, right: 10, fullscreenOnly: false }, playlist: [" & playlists(countinner + (countouter * tour.num_cols)) & "], clip: { provider: 'CYBERCO', live: true, onBegin: function () { clearTimer(); }, onBeforeFinish: function () { this.getPlugin('play').hide(); return false;   } }, onLoad: function () { setTimer(); }, onPlaylistReplace: function () { setTimer(); }, onError: function () { error(); }, play:{ opacity:0.0, label:null, replayLabel: null }, onFinish: function(){ this.play(); }, plugins: { CYBERCO: { url: '../flowplayer/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.3.swf', live: true, controls: { autoHide: true}}} })")
            'logo: { url:'/first_resp/images/cyberco-banner.gif', opacity: 0.4, bottom: 20, right: 20 }, 
            ' rstr.AppendLine("flowplayer('player" & (countinner + (countouter * tour.num_cols)) & "', '../flowplayer/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.5.swf', {  key: '#$34tg5y5y5hytr', logo: { url:'..images/CYBERLOGO.PNG', opacity: 0.65, top: 10, right: 10, fullscreenOnly: false }, playlist: [" & playlists(countinner + (countouter * tour.num_cols)) & "], clip: { provider: 'CYBERCO', live: true, onBegin: function () { clearTimer(); }, onBeforeFinish: function () { this.getPlugin('play').hide(); } }, onLoad: function () { setTimer(); }, onPlaylistReplace: function () { setTimer(); }, onError: function () { error(); }, plugins: { CYBERCO: { url: '../flowplayer/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.3.swf', live: true, controls: { autoHide: true}}} })")
            countinner += 1
        Loop Until countinner = tour.num_cols

        countouter += 1
        countinner = 0
    Loop Until countouter = tour.num_rows
    rstr.AppendLine("</script>")
    Me.litCreatePlayersScript.Text = rstr.ToString
End Sub

Public Function loadWallData(ByVal wstr As String) As DataSet
    Try
        'If Me.loggedin Then 
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("timsConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Dim dsStreams As New DataSet
        'add the quotes to the strings 
        wstr = wstr.Replace(",", "','")
        wstr = "'" & wstr & "'"

        Dim sqltext As String = "[User_SelectVWallStreams]  " & wstr
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim Command As New SqlCommand
        Command = New SqlCommand(sqltext, conn)
        'Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        da.SelectCommand = Command
        da.Fill(dsStreams)
        Return dsStreams
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function

Protected Sub SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Response.Redirect("../vwall/vwall_tour.aspx?tour_id=" & ddlAvailableTours.SelectedValue)
End Sub

Protected Sub ddlAvailableTours_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlAvailableTours.SelectedIndexChanged
    If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then

        Dim thisUser As New cyberUser(User.Identity.Name, (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("timsConnectionString").ToString()))

        ''load the page 

        Dim selected_tour_id As Integer
        selected_tour_id = ddlAvailableTours.SelectedValue

        If selected_tour_id = thisUser.default_tour_id Then
            Me.btnSetDefaultTour.Enabled = False
        Else

            Me.btnSetDefaultTour.Enabled = True
        End If
        Dim t As user_Tour
        For Each t In thisUser.user_Tours
            If t.tour_id = selected_tour_id Then
                'selected_tour_id = ddlAvailableTours.SelectedValue
                writeTableString(t)
                writeScriptForPlayers(t)
                ' Response.Redirect("../vwall/vwall_tour.aspx?tour_id=" & selected_tour_id)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub btnSetDefaultTour_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSetDefaultTour.Click
    If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
        Dim thisUser As New cyberUser(User.Identity.Name, (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("timsConnectionString").ToString()))
        thisUser.UpdateDefaultTour(Me.ddlAvailableTours.SelectedValue)
        Me.btnSetDefaultTour.Enabled = False
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub btnSignOut_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSignOut.Click
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
    'delete the cookie (or will be infinite loop) 
    'delete the cookie 
    Dim aCookie As HttpCookie
    If Request.Cookies("cyber_Load") Is Nothing Then
        'Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie)
        Response.Redirect("../default.aspx")
    Else
        aCookie = Request.Cookies("cyber_Load")
        aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1D)
        Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie)
        Response.Redirect("../default.aspx")
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: xxz (awefull name btw) is Shared, [it might not be doing what you expect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939395/public-shared-variable-shared-between-users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that is:

```
Public Shared xxz(9) As String
```

By declaring the variable as `Shared`, there only ever exists one instance of the variable, shared by all users. Whatever one user puts in the variable is visible to all other users.

You would rather store the array in the `Session` collection, so that each user can have one array of their own.

Declare the array variable as an instance variable, so that it's local to the current page, and don't create the actual array yet:

```
Public xxz As String()
```

In the beginning of the code, get the array from the `Session` collection, or create a new one if there is no array since before:

```
xxz = DirectCast(Session("xxz"), String())
If xxz Is Nothing Then
  ReDim xxz(9)
  Session("xxz") = xxz
End If
```